# Sound for collision only once

Tags: triggers, processing

Ive got the following code to check for agent collision.
I want to fire  a MIDI message only once when they start colliding.

Ive got this so far.

```
void draw(){
        //Loop through people, and check collision, then play note, if intersecting
        for(int i=0;i<people.size();i++){
          Person p = people.get(i);
          p.collide(people,collisions);
          p.triggerMidi();
          p.run();
        }
  }



  public void collide(ArrayList<Person> people, ArrayList<Person> connections) {
   for(Person other : people) {
   if (other != this) {
    if (this.collide(other)) {
      this.isIntersecting=true;
     //connections.add(other); // when a collision is found, add it to a list for later use.
    }
  }
}
}

void triggerMidi(){
     if(!hasPlayed && this.isIntersecting==true){
      MIDI.sendNoteOn(channel, agentNote, 127); 
      delay(200);
      MIDI.sendNoteOff(channel,agentNote, 127);
      hasPlayed=true;
   }
}
```

This works to play the sound only once at the start of collision.
But how do I get it to play again at the start of another collision.

Obviously I have to set hasPlayed back to false.
But where?

When I set it to false in the collide loop, the sound play a million times.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First off, you probably shouldn't have a call to `delay()` from your drawing thread. That will cause your sketch to become laggy and unresponsive. Instead, you might want to put your sound playing on a different thread.

Then, to answer your original question- do you know how long the note plays for? If so, just record the time that the note starts, and then use that time to check the elapsed time. The [millis()](https://www.processing.org/reference/millis_.html) function might come in handy for that. When the elapsed time is greater than the duration of the note, then you can set `hasPlayed` back to false.

Comment: How do I play sound on a different thread?? Never dealt with multiple threads in processing.

Comment: Ok, I figured out threading using the simple thread() function in processing.  But now, how do I pass arguments to that function?? Seems I can only pass a String into the thread,  Like thread("runThisFunction").  But what if runThisFunction() takes 2 arguments.  I cant do thread("runThisFunction(arg,arg2)");  Any idea?

Comment: @KyleK Either use a variable at the top of your sketch, or look into Java threading. Anything you can do in Java, you can do in Processing- assuming you're not deploying as JavaScript.